# Can there be metrics on sets of random variables?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, random-variables, expectation

First off - I do not know much probability theory, so please pardon me if this question is nonsensical.

The question arose from the following thought: can I make the expectation function continuous, by assigning to a set of random variables (say, those with finite expectation), some sort of metric (or even, just a topology)?

Would be interested to hear about this, if the question makes sense.

Comment: The Ky Fan metric, which is used for convergence in probability, may be relevant here. See for example here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202346/is-the-metric-induced-by-convergence-in-probability-ky-fan-metric-complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious example is the $L^1$ norm:
$$\|X\|=E(|X|).$$
For different notions of convergence of random variables see... [Convergence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables.).